# GET (405) method not allowed

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to display mysql db data using yajra datatables. But there is a error.
[image]

this is my controller

public function ajaxservice(Request $request){

```
$service = servicesModel::all();

if($request->ajax){

 return DataTables::of($service)->make(true); 

}
```

this is my route

```
   Route::post('/services/recieve', [serviceController::class,'ajaxservice'])->name('service.ajaxservice');
```

this is blade

```
$(document).ready( function () {


  $.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

});

```
$('#service').DataTable({

    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax:"{{ route('service.ajaxservice') }}",

    columns: [
        {data: 'id'},
        {data: 'service'},
      
    ]
});
```

Comment: You are sending a `GET` request to a `POST` route (`Route::post`). If you want to do that, you need `Route::get`.

Comment: mention method post .
  ajax: {
            url: "{{ route('service.ajaxservice') }}",
            type: 'POST',
        },